# Do I need to check for null in Loan Pattern

Tags: scala

Here is a common example of loan pattern:

```
def using[A <: {def close() : Unit}, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B =
   try {
       f(param)
   } finally {
       param.close()
   }
```

Do I need to take care of NPE and add check?

```
def using[A <: {def close() : Unit}, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B =
   try {
       f(param)
   } finally {
        if (param != null) param.close()
   }
```

Comment: This is on a case by case basis, there are no complete answers to cover this. If you think the resource might be nulled out or be null at the use-site, then check for null. Also, note that if performance is of any concern, using structural types resorts to run-time reflection. Perhaps you can leverage the existing `Closable` interface defined in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If nulling out the resource is a legitimate use of the API, then check for `null`. Don't check it just because it's technically possible for a reference type to contain null, or you'll be checking for null every other line of code.

Answer (score -2):

This is where Unit Testing (and maybe even TDD) would be helpful. You should be testing every possible scenario and making sure your function behaves like it should.

In answer to your question - there's nothing wrong with accounting for fringe cases if you think they can be hit. However, I think that if the `null` would throw an exception in your function, it should be put in a `catch` bracket instead, something like:

```
def using[A <: {def close() : Unit}, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B = {
  try {
    f(param)
    param.close()
  } catch {
    case e: RuntimeException => ???
    case e: NullPointerException => ???
    case e: Exception => ??? // do something with the exceptions
  }
}
```

This way, you can handle the exceptions as you see fit. Of course, you can always add a `finally` bracket too, or move `param.close()` back into the `finally` if it suits your needs.

Comment: The code snippet in your answer is not Loan Pattern. Also, it is not about best practices, it is about the pattern which is more or less fixed.

Comment: If you're not sure that the param is not null the standard way is to use Option[A] and then either check the isEmty or use map/flatMap/forEach inside the f. At leas if (param != null) is definitely non-functional way...

Comment: @Alex I agree that is not nice, but I did not noticed any preconditions for this pattern regarding null. There are even examples where database connections are created with this pattern.

Comment: How is unit-testing helpful when dealing with `null`? Every reference type could "possibly" contain null.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco if `null` is a valid case which could be hit in practice, it should be tested for so you can be sure you're handling it correctly. I don't see how getting high test coverage and testing for edge cases is a negative thing.

Comment: As with most tools, unit testing produces diminishing returns as you stray from its intended purpose. I can certainly be a bad thing when miss-used, one example: increasing the maintenance burden of an oversized test code base (which is likely to contain its own bugs). Granted, it's a very useful tool, but not quite on the category of "couldn't possibly be a bad thing".